# Grsync does not finish transfer (stuck)

Tags: rsync

A directory with files is to be moved to a NAS.    For some reason it becomes stuck in the sense that the upper progress bar indicates 100%, though global progress remains at 90%:

[image]

I removed .lnk files in the payload.   That helped somewhat, but now it is stuck elsewhere. I think that grsync was endlessly traversing the directory in the sym-link?

Is there another file type similar to .lnk that is causing a "recursive" problem?